# PinchZoom and paning using surfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, pinchzoom

I am developing a RDP application using android 3.0. I am using surface view to display the images. Is there any way to implement pinch zoom functionality for surface view(I am trying to zoom the image).

Answer (score 0):

Subclass surfaceview and implements `onTouchEvent()`. Use a GestureDetector and GestureListener to modify a matrix representing the current state of manipulation and draw your canvas modified by this matrix.

It works, but is a piece of software to figure out. Took me around 6 weeks to have everything set up correctly, especially if you want some overlay items which also listen to touch events. I'd think about publishing that code, but it's company code...